# Material UI - How to add onChange method to pre-made components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using creative-tim's materia kit react template here:

https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-kit-react/?_ga=2.145959732.1805770478.1593490128-1778058995.1593310826#/documentation/inputs

and his customerInput components doesn't have an onChange method! Anybody know how to handle user inputs using this template?

Here is use case for a customerInput component:

```
                   <CustomInput
                      labelText="First Name..."
                      id="first"
                      formControlProps={{
                        fullWidth: true,
                      }}
                      inputProps={{
                        type: 'text',
                        endAdornment: (
                          <InputAdornment position="end">
                            <People className={classes.inputIconsColor} />
                          </InputAdornment>
                        ),
                      }}
                    />
```

and here is its component code

```
export default function CustomInput(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const {
    formControlProps,
    labelText,
    id,
    labelProps,
    inputProps,
    error,
    white,
    inputRootCustomClasses,
    success,
  } = props;

  const labelClasses = classNames({
    [' ' + classes.labelRootError]: error,
    [' ' + classes.labelRootSuccess]: success && !error,
  });
  const underlineClasses = classNames({
    [classes.underlineError]: error,
    [classes.underlineSuccess]: success && !error,
    [classes.underline]: true,
    [classes.whiteUnderline]: white,
  });
  const marginTop = classNames({
    [inputRootCustomClasses]: inputRootCustomClasses !== undefined,
  });
  const inputClasses = classNames({
    [classes.input]: true,
    [classes.whiteInput]: white,
  });
  let formControlClasses;
  if (formControlProps !== undefined) {
    formControlClasses = classNames(
        formControlProps.className,
        classes.formControl,
    );
  } else {
    formControlClasses = classes.formControl;
  }
  return (
    <FormControl {...formControlProps} className={formControlClasses}>
      {labelText !== undefined ? (
        <InputLabel
          className={classes.labelRoot + ' ' + labelClasses}
          htmlFor={id}
          {...labelProps}
        >
          {labelText}
        </InputLabel>
      ) : null}
      <Input
        classes={{
          input: inputClasses,
          root: marginTop,
          disabled: classes.disabled,
          underline: underlineClasses,
        }}
        id={id}
        {...inputProps}
      />
    </FormControl>
  );
}

CustomInput.propTypes = {
  labelText: PropTypes.node,
  labelProps: PropTypes.object,
  id: PropTypes.string,
  inputProps: PropTypes.object,
  formControlProps: PropTypes.object,
  inputRootCustomClasses: PropTypes.string,
  error: PropTypes.bool,
  success: PropTypes.bool,
  white: PropTypes.bool,
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but I think you can do it like this:

```js
<CustomInput inputProps={{ onChange: function(e) { console.log('Do stuff') }} />
```